# How to create aliases for variables inside an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alias

I'm working on a jQuery plugin with some user definable variables.

```
(function ($) {
    var defaults = {
        foo: [{bar: 'bar'}]
    }

    $.fn.fooBar = function (config) {
        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, config);

        $.each(settings.foo, function(key, value){
            console.log(value.bar);  // prints 'bar'
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Now I'd like to be able to call this as follows

```
// notice how I've capitalized 'bar' as the variable name
$(document).fooBar({foo: [{Bar: 'Bar'}]});​  // DOES NOT WORK

// and
$(document).fooBar({foo: [{bar: 'bar'}]});  // WORKS
```

So essentially I need to be able to create an alias for `bar` for both capital or lower case. How can I achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: `settings.foo` is an array, not an object (`settings.foo.bar` won't work).  Do you want the object passed in to be set to (or copied into) `settings.foo`?

Comment: no, sorry... my mistake. I need to be able to call `settings.foo.bar`, but the end user needs to be able to use both of the examples I showed in the question. Sorry for the confusion, I'm quite new to some of this javascript stuff.

Comment: Your `$.extend` will replace `defaults.foo` with `config.foo`.  You may need to make your own loop to set the `settings`.

Comment: fixed the *`undefined`* error in my example.

Comment: @Rocket, would you take a look at my answer and lend some quick insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right way to go about it, but here's how I've achieved what I need.

```
(function ($) {
    var defaults = {
        foo: [{bar: 'system bar'}]
    }

    $.fn.fooBar = function (config) {
        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, config);

        $.each(settings.foo, function(key, value){
            // A quick check to see if the user is using capital letters
            // or lower case letters. We can be flexable as long as they're 
            // being consistent.
            if (typeof this.Bar !== 'undefined') {
                this.bar = this.Bar;
            }
            console.log(value.bar);  // prints 'user Bar'
        });
    };
})(jQuery);



$(document).fooBar({foo: 
    [
        { bar: 'lower user bar'}, 
        { Bar: 'UPPER user Bar'}
    ]
});
```

Comment: So, `settings.foo` is an array of objects?  So, do you really need the `$.each`?  Will `settings.foo` ever have more elements in the array (not the object inside it)?  Couldn't you just do `settings.foo[0].bar` (will there ever be a `settings.foo[1]`)?

Comment: yes it's an array. I'm working with Bing Maps and I'm dropping map pins on a map. There could be one or ten pins. `{mapPins: [{lat: 1, lon: 1}, {lat: 1.1, lon: 1.1}]}`

Comment: and the reason for wanting to be case insensitive for the first character is because the javascript standard is to use lowercase, and the VB.Net standard (where I'm serializing the data from) requires upper case properties. `{mapPins: [{Lat: 1, Lon: 1}, {Lat: 1.1, Lon: 1.1}]}`. I realize this isn't required, but it's a good learning experience for me.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize the key case of your config map, and extend off that rather than the one passed in.